# Record copy paste and delete for multiple cells in Audit Trail

Tags: excel, vba

I found a simple code to make an Audit Trail but it works only for single cells.

If someone copy pastes a few cells it stops working. Same for deleting a few cells at once.

```
Option Explicit
Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
 If target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
 Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 22).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & _
  Application.UserName & " / changed cell " & target.Address _
  & "  /from/ " & PreviousValue & " to " & target.Value
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub worksheet_selectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
  PreviousValue = target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need this to work when the copied range is not the same size as the target range? E.g. you copy multiple cells but then select one cell and paste? I might have a solution for the scenario when the source and target ranges are the same size.

Comment: So I need solution in 2 cases: Case 1: I copy for example Range("A2:A50") in Range(B4:B54). And Case 2: I delete some cells like Range("A:D") and it will be dokumented with old values and new values. **Range is the same size but not necessery same Columns or Rows**. I don't want to copy bigger range in smaller one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here's something that works when the copied range and the selected range are the same size. E.g. you copy A1:B5, then select some other range that is 5 rows and 2 columns, and paste.

First add two class modules named VirtualCell and VirtualRange:

VirtualCell:

```
Option Explicit

Private pRow As Integer
Private pColumn As Integer
Private pValue As String


Public Property Get vRow() As Integer
    vRow = pRow
End Property

Public Property Let vRow(lRow As Integer)
    pRow = lRow
End Property

Public Property Get vColumn() As Integer
    vColumn = pColumn
End Property

Public Property Let vColumn(lColumn As Integer)
    pColumn = lColumn
End Property

Public Property Get vValue() As String
    vValue = pValue
End Property

Public Property Let vValue(lValue As String)
    pValue = lValue
End Property
```

VirtualRange:

```
Option Explicit

Private pCells As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pCells = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get vCells() As Collection
    Set vCells = pCells
End Property

Public Property Let vCells(lCells As Collection)
    pCells = lCells
End Property

Public Function GetvCell(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal col As Integer) As VirtualCell

    Dim vCell As VirtualCell

    For Each vCell In pCells
        If vCell.vColumn = col And vCell.vRow = row Then
            Set GetvCell = vCell
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then paste this in your worksheet code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim vRange As VirtualRange

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range

    Set vRange = New VirtualRange

    For Each rngCell In Target.Cells
        Dim vCell As VirtualCell
        Set vCell = New VirtualCell

        vCell.vColumn = rngCell.Column
        vCell.vRow = rngCell.row
        vCell.vValue = CStr(rngCell.Value2)

        vRange.vCells.Add vCell
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In Target.Cells
        If rngCell.Value <> vRange.GetvCell(rngCell.row, rngCell.Column).vValue Then
        Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & _
             Application.UserName & " / changed cell " & rngCell.Address _
             & "  /from/ " & vRange.GetvCell(rngCell.row, rngCell.Column).vValue & " to " & rngCell.Value
        End If
    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Failure '91' Objectvariable or With-Blockvariable not defined. At that line: `If rngCell.Value <> vRange.GetvCell(rngCell.row, rngCell.Column).vValue Then`

Comment: Yes, this happens when the copied range and the selected range are different size.

Comment: Yes:-). I marked the first cell not the whole row. Thanks for your help. I can tell them to mark the whole range. It will work fine for us. I will write Messeage Box as warrning if they do it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable to you to limit the user in what they can do, then you can try simply enforcing a "one cell at a time" policy:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False ' To stop an infinite loop
            .Undo
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        MsgBox "Please change only one cell at a time."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
        Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 22).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & _
        Application.UserName & " / changed cell " & target.Address _
        & "  /from/ " & PreviousValue & " to " & target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here's a version which works for ranges. As long as the ranges are the same dimensions:

```
Dim RangeValues As Variant
Dim lCols As Long, lRows As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> RangeValues Then
            Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 22).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & UN & " / changed cell " & Target.Address & "  /from/ " & RangeValues & " to " & Target.Value
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' More than one cell in the range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To lRows
        For c = 1 To lCols
            If Target.Cells(r, c).Value <> RangeValues(r, c) Then
                Sheets("LOG").Cells(65000, 22).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now & " / " & UN & " / changed cell " & Target.Cells(r, c).Address & "  /from/ " & RangeValues(r, c) & " to " & Target.Cells(r, c).Value
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    RangeValues = Target.Value
    lCols = Target.Columns.Count
    lRows = Target.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly by they need to copy some ranges. So this policy won't work in that case.

Comment: You'd need to store an array of values, in that case. PreviousValue should be a Variant, and you'd need to write extra code to store the range's values within that 2D array. Then you'd need to compare each value individually, to decide whether to log it. It'd get complicated if the pasted range were a different size to the copied range. I suggest you think carefully about exactly what functionality you want, and in which scenario.

Comment: **Size copied = size pasted** it's sure. I need 2 codes: one for ranges of that same size and one, which is already ready for single cells. I need too scenario to use **.delete** for few cells together. It's getting now too complex to write it...